# Make Typography "paragraph based"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to display a very long string on a page using a single Material UI Typography. I would like to display it as a text with some paragraphs, however, reading the docs I found that Typography has only a `paragraph` prop on it, and I guess I'd have to break my long string into small pieces of Typographies. But, once the data is coming as a string from the DB, would there be a better approach for this matter?

this is my display page
[displayPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksqe6.png)

this is my DB (I'm using mongoDB Atlas, btw)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn3Sg.png)

Comment: can you explain with an example ?

Comment: sure! I added two screenshots

Comment: I have a question about this. How would you divide the text into paragraphs(On what condition)?
It's good to store the content in paragraphs into DB itself so that you don't need to do any manipulations on UI

Comment: @mchowdam I thought about that. It's my last resort.

Comment: @YassineCHABLI Thank you for your help, but it won't work the way I intended... I guess I'll have to separate the paragraphs before sending them to the DB anyway...

Comment: Yes, that is the perfect way.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's hard to have a rule for separating. but i think you are looking to separate the long text into paragraphs based on dot as indicator of paragraph end.

Here is an example that could help you

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-forked-mh1t6h?file=/index.js

NB:
This example can't handle all possibilities since ther is a lot of options when this snippet can't work for you.

Example :

if you have a text like :

```
This is the verions 1.4.5
```

In that case , you are going to have each number in paragraph

Solution:

First of all , think about all possibility that you may have in the usecase & try to build a regex.

And then , pass the regex to the split function , so that way you could handle this issue.